# I just can't figure out how to retrieve the name and value of the object passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function show, what it basically does is display the nodes and attributes of my xml. I created an object attributes to store the name and value of each attribute. This part is working well. Now, when I pass this object to another function I just cant retrieve the name and value of the attributes. It says that aname and avalue are undefined. Can somebody please help?

My code:

```
function show(){
  :
  var mytag2 = child.nodeName;
  var mytagvalue2 = child.textContent;
  var attributes = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < child.attributes.length; k++) {
     var attrib = child.attributes[k];
     if (attrib.specified === true) {
        attributes.push({aname: attrib.name, avalue: attrib.value});
        $("#maincontent").append("<li>" + attributes[k].aname + " = " +  
        attributes[k].avalue + "</li>");
     }
  }

  $("#maincontent").append("<td><button id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show('" + mytag2 + "','" + mytagvalue2 + "','" + attributes + "')\">Edit</button></td><td></td></tr>");
}

function div_show(tag, tcontent, attributes){
  for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    var target = document.getElementById('attributes');
    target.innerHTML = '';
    target.innerHTML += "<input id=" + "'" + attributes[i].aname + "'" + " " + 
   "type = text" + " " + "name=" + "'" + attributes[i].aname + "'" + ">";

    document.getElementById("'" + attributes[i].aname + "'").value = 
    attributes[i].aname;
    document.getElementById("'" + attributes[i].avalue + "'").value =  
    attributes[i].avalue;      
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling your functions? What line specifically does the error pop up?

Comment: $("#maincontent").append("<td><button id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show('" + mytag2 + "','" + mytagvalue2 + "','" + attributes + "')\">Edit</button></td><td></td></tr>");   I have a button edit. The onclick event calls div_show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into a discussion about why you should do all of this differently, I'll point out the problem, and how you could fix it.

In your code, you are creating a string:

```
$("#maincontent").append("<td><button id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show('" + mytag2 + "','" + mytagvalue2 + "','" + attributes + "')\">Edit</button></td><td></td></tr>");
```

`attributes` is an array object, and this will call the `toString()` method on it in order to concatenate it to the string that is being built. That will render it as `[object Object]`.

You should serialize it to JSON, and concatenate that instead (also remove the quotes around the string since you want to pass your array object).

```
$("#maincontent").append("<td><button id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show('" + mytag2 + "','" + mytagvalue2 + "'," + JSON.stringify(attributes) + ")\">Edit</button></td><td></td></tr>");
```

This would produce a string that looks like the array you want to pass:

```
[{"aname":"someName","avalue":"someValue"}]
```

---

Here is a simplified example that shows what I'm talking about:

```js
var attributes = [
  { aname: 'test1', avalue: 'test1' },
  { aname: 'test2', avalue: 'test2' }
];


var arrayConcatenated = 'Array Concatenated: ' + attributes;
var arrayJSONConcatenated = 'Array JSON Concatenated: ' + JSON.stringify(attributes);

document.getElementById('arrayConcatenated').innerHTML = arrayConcatenated;
document.getElementById('arrayJSONConcatenated').innerHTML = arrayJSONConcatenated;
```

```html
<div id="arrayConcatenated"></div>
vs.
<div id="arrayJSONConcatenated"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I now understand the concept better.